# Mapbox GL - highlight features and queryRenderedFeatures() while allowing basemap style change

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I need to be able to highlight features in a bounding box using Mapbox GL as shown in [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/using-box-queryrenderedfeatures/). My map also needs to have the ability to change the style layer, e.g. changing the base style from `mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10` to `mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9`. This has been challenging because Mapbox GL does not natively support the concept of "basemaps" like, e.g. leaflet does.

My solution, after much searching (I believe I eventually followed a workaround posted in a github issue) involved:

1. Using `map.on('style.load')` instead of `map.on('load')` as shown in the example (I believe `map.on('style.load')` is not part of their public API, but I could be wrong) and,
2. Iterating through an array of sources/layers (see the `vectorTileLayers` variable in the code below) to add vector tiles layers to the map every time a new style is loaded.

This works brilliantly for me in some ways - I'm able to add an arbitrary number of vector tile sources to the array, and they are all added back to the map if the base style is changed. However, I am unable to add a query feature following the example provided by Mapbox if the sources/layers are added to the map in an array and iterated through as shown below. The bounding feature works, but when it is drawn, and released, I see the error show by running the snippet below.

This is a simplified version my actual problem that will allow others to run and manipulate the code. In reality, I'm adding my own vector tile layers (stored in the `vectorTileLayers` array, which works without issue. When I try and add another layer with the same source and different styling, as shown in the example, I'm unable to actually query the desired layer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Just FYI - the toggleable layers buttons are not showing up in this snippet, but it's not critical to solve the problem.

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamFtZXljc21pdGgiLCJhIjoiY2p4NTRzdTczMDA1dzRhbXBzdmFpZXV6eCJ9.-k7Um-xmYy4xhNDN6kDvpg';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
      center: [-98, 38.88],
      minZoom: 2,
      zoom: 3
    });

    var vectorTileLayers = [{
        source: {
          type: 'vector',
          url: 'mapbox://mapbox.82pkq93d'
        },
        layer: {
          id: 'counties',
          type: 'fill',
          source: 'counties',
          'source-layer': 'original',
          paint: {
            'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
            'fill-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
          },
        }
      },
      {
        source: {
          type: 'vector',
          url: 'mapbox://mapbox.82pkq93d'
        },
        layer: {
          id: 'counties-highlighted',
          type: 'fill',
          source: 'counties',
          'source-layer': 'original',
          paint: {
            'fill-outline-color': '#484896',
            'fill-color': '#6e599f',
            'fill-opacity': 0.75
          },
          filter: ['in', 'FIPS', '']
        }
      }
    ]

    map.on('style.load', function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < vectorTileLayers.length; i++) {
        var tileLayer = vectorTileLayers[i];
        map.addSource(tileLayer.layer.source, tileLayer.source);
        map.addLayer(tileLayer.layer);
      }

      var layerList = document.getElementById('basemapmenu');
      var inputs = layerList.getElementsByTagName('input');

      function switchLayer(layer) {
        var layerId = layer.target.id;
        map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/' + layerId);
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].onclick = switchLayer;
      }

    });

    // Disable default box zooming.
    map.boxZoom.disable();

    // Create a popup, but don't add it to the map yet.
    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
      closeButton: false
    });

    var canvas = map.getCanvasContainer();

    var start;
    var current;
    var box;

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, true);
    // Return the xy coordinates of the mouse position
    function mousePos(e) {
      var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      return new mapboxgl.Point(
        e.clientX - rect.left - canvas.clientLeft,
        e.clientY - rect.top - canvas.clientTop
      );
    }

    function mouseDown(e) {
      // Continue the rest of the function if the shiftkey is pressed.
      if (!(e.shiftKey && e.button === 0)) return;

      // Disable default drag zooming when the shift key is held down.
      map.dragPan.disable();

      // Call functions for the following events
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
      document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);

      // Capture the first xy coordinates
      start = mousePos(e);
    }

    function onMouseMove(e) {
      // Capture the ongoing xy coordinates
      current = mousePos(e);

      // Append the box element if it doesnt exist
      if (!box) {
        box = document.createElement('div');
        box.classList.add('boxdraw');
        canvas.appendChild(box);
      }

      var minX = Math.min(start.x, current.x),
        maxX = Math.max(start.x, current.x),
        minY = Math.min(start.y, current.y),
        maxY = Math.max(start.y, current.y);

      // Adjust width and xy position of the box element ongoing
      var pos = 'translate(' + minX + 'px,' + minY + 'px)';
      box.style.transform = pos;
      box.style.WebkitTransform = pos;
      box.style.width = maxX - minX + 'px';
      box.style.height = maxY - minY + 'px';
    }

    function onMouseUp(e) {
      // Capture xy coordinates
      finish([start, mousePos(e)]);
    }

    function onKeyDown(e) {
      // If the ESC key is pressed
      if (e.keyCode === 27) finish();
    }

    function finish(bbox) {
      // Remove these events now that finish has been called.
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);

      if (box) {
        box.parentNode.removeChild(box);
        box = null;
      }

      // If bbox exists. use this value as the argument for `queryRenderedFeatures`
      if (bbox) {
        var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(bbox, {
          layers: ['counties']
        });

        if (features.length >= 1000) {
          return window.alert('Select a smaller number of features');
        }

        // Run through the selected features and set a filter
        // to match features with unique FIPS codes to activate
        // the `counties-highlighted` layer.
        var filter = features.reduce(
          function(memo, feature) {
            memo.push(feature.properties.FIPS);
            return memo;
          },
          ['in', 'FIPS']
        );

        map.setFilter('counties-highlighted', filter);
      }

      map.dragPan.enable();
    }

    map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
      var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
        layers: ['counties-highlighted']
      });
      // Change the cursor style as a UI indicator.
      map.getCanvas().style.cursor = features.length ? 'pointer' : '';

      if (!features.length) {
        popup.remove();
        return;
      }

      var feature = features[0];

      popup
        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .setText(feature.properties.COUNTY)
        .addTo(map);
    });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#basemapmenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.boxdraw {
  background: rgba(56, 135, 190, 0.1);
  border: 2px solid #3887be;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>

<div id='basemapmenu'>
    <input id='light-v10' class='btn btn-outline-primary' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='Light' checked='checked'>
    <input id='dark-v10' class='btn btn-outline-primary' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='Dark'>
    <input id='satellite-v9' class='btn btn-outline-primary' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='Satellite'>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran you code locally and found the problem!

You are trying to add same source twice and mapbox was giving you error for that, if you check your Console:

Problem: There can be only one source with one ID on Map

```
Error: There is already a source with this ID
```

After first loop execute successfully. On second iteration, it fails to add same source twice, code breaks here and doesn't  continue further. Hence doesn't add second layer(therefore no functionality works thereafter!)

Fix:(Added a small check to not add same source if already added)

```
map.on('style.load', function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < vectorTileLayers.length; i++) {
                var tileLayer = vectorTileLayers[i];
                if (!map.getSource(tileLayer.layer.source,)) //FIX
                    map.addSource(tileLayer.layer.source, tileLayer.source);
                map.addLayer(tileLayer.layer);
            }

            var layerList = document.getElementById('basemapmenu');
            var inputs = layerList.getElementsByTagName('input');

            function switchLayer(layer) {
                var layerId = layer.target.id;
                map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/' + layerId);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                inputs[i].onclick = switchLayer;
            }

        });
```

I can see the Code is working fine:
[image]

Hope this will fix the problem.

Comment: This is great thanks so much! Just a quick note in case people come across this in the future: after some more digging it looks like the public and correct version of `map.on('style.load' ...)` is `map.on('styleata' ...)`. From what I can tell, the functionality is the same, at as far as swapping "baselayers" is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the above answer from Dolly as accepted because it answers my original question exactly. Unforunately, it didn't exactly solve my actual problem. After some additional fiddling, I wanted to post a fully functional version for reference in case people come across this looking for a solution to adding toggleable "basemap" layers in Mapbox GL with or without user interactivity options like this one.

The solution above does not work after toggling between basemap layers. The vector tile layers are not reloaded properly. The solution below seems to do the trick. It uses `map.on('styledata' ...)` rather than `map.on('style.load' ...)`, which seems to allow for loading layers by the more conventional method of first calling `map.addSource()` followed by `map.addLayer()`. You can load a single source, and then an arbitrary number of layers pointing to that source. So in my "real world" example, I load 3 sources, and 5 layers from those sources.

(FYI - for some reason the built-in snippet tool from stack overflow isn't rendering the basemap buttons. If you copy the code exactly into JS fiddle or codepen it will work)

I hope this helps future humans - it seems like lots of people have had problems with managing Mapbox styles with custom layers on top. I certainly have.

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken =
  "pk.eyJ1IjoiamFtZXljc21pdGgiLCJhIjoiY2p4NTRzdTczMDA1dzRhbXBzdmFpZXV6eCJ9.-k7Um-xmYy4xhNDN6kDvpg";
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: "map",
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10",
  center: [-98, 38.88],
  minZoom: 2,
  zoom: 3
});

map.on("styledata", function() {
  map.addSource("counties", {
    type: "vector",
    url: "mapbox://mapbox.82pkq93d"
  });

  map.addLayer({
    id: "counties",
    type: "fill",
    source: "counties",
    "source-layer": "original",
    paint: {
      "fill-outline-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
      "fill-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"
    }
  });

  map.addLayer({
    id: "counties-highlighted",
    type: "fill",
    source: "counties",
    "source-layer": "original",
    paint: {
      "fill-outline-color": "#484896",
      "fill-color": "#6e599f",
      "fill-opacity": 0.75
    },
    filter: ["in", "FIPS", ""]
  });

  var layerList = document.getElementById("basemapmenu");
  var inputs = layerList.getElementsByTagName("input");

  function switchLayer(layer) {
    var layerId = layer.target.id;
    map.setStyle("mapbox://styles/mapbox/" + layerId);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onclick = switchLayer;
  }
});

// Disable default box zooming.
map.boxZoom.disable();

// Create a popup, but don't add it to the map yet.
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
  closeButton: false
});

var canvas = map.getCanvasContainer();

var start;
var current;
var box;

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, true);
// Return the xy coordinates of the mouse position
function mousePos(e) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return new mapboxgl.Point(
    e.clientX - rect.left - canvas.clientLeft,
    e.clientY - rect.top - canvas.clientTop
  );
}

function mouseDown(e) {
  // Continue the rest of the function if the shiftkey is pressed.
  if (!(e.shiftKey && e.button === 0)) return;

  // Disable default drag zooming when the shift key is held down.
  map.dragPan.disable();

  // Call functions for the following events
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);

  // Capture the first xy coordinates
  start = mousePos(e);
}

function onMouseMove(e) {
  // Capture the ongoing xy coordinates
  current = mousePos(e);

  // Append the box element if it doesnt exist
  if (!box) {
    box = document.createElement("div");
    box.classList.add("boxdraw");
    canvas.appendChild(box);
  }

  var minX = Math.min(start.x, current.x),
    maxX = Math.max(start.x, current.x),
    minY = Math.min(start.y, current.y),
    maxY = Math.max(start.y, current.y);

  // Adjust width and xy position of the box element ongoing
  var pos = "translate(" + minX + "px," + minY + "px)";
  box.style.transform = pos;
  box.style.WebkitTransform = pos;
  box.style.width = maxX - minX + "px";
  box.style.height = maxY - minY + "px";
}

function onMouseUp(e) {
  // Capture xy coordinates
  finish([start, mousePos(e)]);
}

function onKeyDown(e) {
  // If the ESC key is pressed
  if (e.keyCode === 27) finish();
}

function finish(bbox) {
  // Remove these events now that finish has been called.
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  document.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);

  if (box) {
    box.parentNode.removeChild(box);
    box = null;
  }

  // If bbox exists. use this value as the argument for `queryRenderedFeatures`
  if (bbox) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(bbox, {
      layers: ["counties"]
    });

    if (features.length >= 1000) {
      return window.alert("Select a smaller number of features");
    }

    // Run through the selected features and set a filter
    // to match features with unique FIPS codes to activate
    // the `counties-highlighted` layer.
    var filter = features.reduce(
      function(memo, feature) {
        memo.push(feature.properties.FIPS);
        return memo;
      }, ["in", "FIPS"]
    );

    map.setFilter("counties-highlighted", filter);
  }

  map.dragPan.enable();
}

map.on("mousemove", function(e) {
  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
    layers: ["counties-highlighted"]
  });
  // Change the cursor style as a UI indicator.
  map.getCanvas().style.cursor = features.length ? "pointer" : "";

  if (!features.length) {
    popup.remove();
    return;
  }

  var feature = features[0];

  popup.setLngLat(e.lngLat).setText(feature.properties.COUNTY).addTo(map);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#basemapmenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.boxdraw {
  background: rgba(56, 135, 190, 0.1);
  border: 2px solid #3887be;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>

<div id='basemapmenu'>
  <input id='light-v10' class='btn btn-outline-primary' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='Light' checked='checked'>
  <input id='dark-v10' class='btn btn-outline-primary' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='Dark'>
  <input id='satellite-v9' class='btn btn-outline-primary' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='Satellite'>
</div>
```